# Php - How do I use a for loop inside API request

Tags: php, api, foreach, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Here is a sample request which works, but the names are hard coded

```
$client->batchDeleteAttributes(array(
    'DomainName' => $domainName,
    'Items' => array(
         array('Name' => '5149572a86deb5161fbb22bdab',),
         array('Name' => '5149572a86deb5161fbf7487b9',),
     )
));
```

I can get the name values using the following loop

```
foreach($_POST['d'] as $key => $value)
{

}
```

I am confused how to integrate the foreach loop with the api request. I assume I need to create an array using the foreach loop and then use that array in the api request but I don't know the syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the format of your `$_POST` data it's hard to give a detailed solution, but something along these lines should get you heading in the right direction:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($_POST['d'] as $value)
{
    $names[] = array('Name' => $value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!   All I needed to do was add your code and then change the api request to be: 'Items' => $names